# 愛は傷つきやすく translated as "Love is Free"?

Tags: translation, words

A friend of mine has a Japan pop-music CD and on the title there's the following:

ヒデとロザンナ (Hide & Rosanna) - 愛は傷つきやすく (Love is Free)

However, I believe 愛は傷つきやすく rather means "Love is Fragile" and not "Love is Free". Is this my thinking correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right.

**愛は傷つきやすく** can be translated as ”**love is easy to be hurt**" in a literal translation.

But it was translated as “**Love is Free**”. I guess that's may because of its contents of lyrics. You know, some titles or lyrics of the songs weren't translated with a literal translation in order to be easily understood by listeners.